# Page Speed Insights Do Subdomains Affect The Origin Summary?

Tags: google-pagespeed

We recently saw a pretty dramatic drop in rankings for our biggest terms.
Our origin summary has dropped below that of our competitors.

When I run the page speed insights scans on individual pages that I made from scratch, they easily pass. I have another group that get scores around 70-80 (wordpress cms pages). However, the origin summary for the domain fails miserably.

We added a subdomain this fall. The subdomain is store.dme.net and they have terrible scores for mobile. The pages for the subdomain have been showing up on google with higher and higher frequency.

Is it possible that our e-store, `store.example.net` is affecting the overall origin summary score for `example.net`?
Can a subdomain affect the origin summary for the entire domain?

#### Good pages

[image: Good pages on dme.net 1]

#### Meh pages

[image: Meh pages on dme.net]

#### E-store pages

[image: Estore Pages]

Answer (score 4):

For Page Speed Insights, it's not taking into account subdomains unless you test one.

However, on your Core Web Vitals reports in Search Console you might see a bad field data report if you're looking at a domain property because that data would be aggregated.

If something is hosted on a subdomain and loaded in via iframe *that* could cause what you describe.

### To Fix Your Issue

Why not just nip this in the bud? Your homepage definitely has issues. I think most of your problem can be fixed via DOM prioritization.

[image: waterfall of website loading]

Defer or async that js and prioritize your above the fold content via resource hints. Here's a nice mdn article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Performance/Web_Performance_Basics

I've also written a couple other answers on this that will help you out:

[CLS Question Where DOM Priority Was an Issue](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/137769/122139)

[CLS Question Where FCP Image Was an Issue](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/137451/122139)

Load those images as WebP's too unless your target audience uses Internet Explored *(past tense on purpose)*.

Comment: I would, but we use a terrible wordpress plugin / theme called divi. It's a wiziwig. When I edit the actual code on the page, it will get overwritten nearly daily. I used to go in and delete the extra css and javascript that they used. Like they would call a lot of stuff for woocommerce even though our website doesn't use woocommerce. I would go in there and physically delete the code from the theme editor and it would be back either with the next update or with the chron update. I've been begging my work to let me switch to normal wordpress from divi for 2 years now. They won't.

Comment: There have been no major changes to the website, whenever there is a plugin update I test it first too. Most pages either rank ok - good depending if they are divi builder pages or from scratch. https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dme.net%2Fejector-pins.php I'm trying to figure out why the origin summary is so bad. To my understanding, the origin summary is a average of the total of all page speed scores.

Comment: @GuyTryingToSolveAnIssue If you've done all of that, what you should try to do is to get the site on a child theme of Divi. That way your changes wont get overridden. I've been able to get Divi to work just fine with server caching enabled. I'd recommend Varnish Cache. While many would call that overkill, they might have not dealt with divi before.