# Core web vitals - LCP is being recounted on element outside viewport

Tags: seo, html, javascript, css, core-web-vitals

I have been trying to control LCP on my website but unfortunately a strange phenomenon is continuously occurring, An element which is not in viewport is considered to be an LCP.

Opposite to that google's official documentation suggests that upon page load only those elements are counted as LCP which are visible to user in first fold https://web.dev/lcp/

I am using LCP observer to show exact element being considered as LCP, Please refer to screenshots below.

Any help regarding this issue would be really appreciated Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where in the DOM does the `<p><small> text </small></p>` text that is being reported as your LCP exist? Down far by footer? What happens if you drop it from the DOM?

Comment: I'm also curious to know whether this element is being reported in DevTools or if it's coming from your analytics. If it's the latter, keep in mind that what shows in the viewport for you might not show in the viewport for everyone. See: https://web.dev/debug-web-vitals-in-the-field/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How Chrome Measures LCP

- At the start of page load, the browser begins a stopwatch to track time it takes to see the largest content on the page.
- Chrome paints content in a series of stages. Different stages occur as the browser loads content on the page, or when changes are made to the DOM (whether its css, js, etc) and it's got to be *re-painted*.
- In each stage, which I suppose you could think of like a "stroke" (of a paint brush) the browser looks for the largest content that is visible above the fold. After each stage the largest content found is reported.
- If/when the browser finds content that is larger than what it has saved, it makes note of how long it took to see it from when the timer started.
- Once the user starts interacting with the page, the *last reported* largest content is the Largest Contentful Paint time.

For some odd (and ironic) reason, in the last stage, the browser is reporting that element below *is* both **above the fold** and **larger than the last largest thing reported**.

```html
<p class="text-white-50 pt2">
  <small> 
  Example Text
  </small>
</p>
```

The only logical reason I can think of as to why that would occur is because it *was* above the fold. I typically see anomalies like this when there's a lot of render blocking and layout shifting going on.

To fix your problem you first have to understand it.

### Start isolating variables

Ignore LCP for awhile and make sure you've optimized everything *else* that you possibly can.

Make sure you've eliminate all render blocking and layout shifting and *then* test this again.

When all of that is done you *should* be pretty fast. But if this phenomenon persists, add the following directly after your opening `<body>` tag:

```
<img width="99999" height="99999" style="pointer-events: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 99vw; height: 99vh; max-width: 99vw; max-height: 99vh;"  src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48c3ZnIHdpZHRoPSI5OTk5OXB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9Ijk5OTk5cHgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA5OTk5OSA5OTk5OSIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIj48ZyBzdHJva2U9Im5vbmUiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMCI+PHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9Ijk5OTk5IiBoZWlnaHQ9Ijk5OTk5Ij48L3JlY3Q+IDwvZz4gPC9zdmc+">
```

It will work, however this is not intended to be a long term solution.

This should be used as a hack to squash a relentless bug if after you optimize everything this phenomenon still persists. I am **not** advocating that you fool search engines into thinking you have good UX.

---

Here's some other answers I've written to questions about Core Web Vitals that you might find useful:

[Question where site needed to fix DOM priority and provide resource hints](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137996/page-speed-insights-do-subdomains-affect-the-origin-summary/137999)

^ at the end of my answer you'll find links to:

CLS Question Where DOM Priority Was an Issue

CLS Question Where FCP Image Was an Issue

Comment: How do your relentless bug squash hack work?  Is there documentation or explanation about it somewhere?

Comment: Creates a transparent image resized to be just under full screen size. Chrome only looks at the actual pixel dimensions. So even tho it's being resized that's not factored in. That image is the largest thing on the page. I'll try to find a link to the blog post I got it from @StephenOstermiller

Comment: https://www.devisedlabs.com/blog/largest-contentful-paint-lcp-hack

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MikeCiffone but are there any chances that google would penalize websites using hacks like you have mentioned above?

Comment: @Awaisfiaz Penalize? Unlikely. For example Google has shifted from a _penalizing_ sites engaging in link schemes  to simply _ignoring backlinks_ believed to be paid for. Worst case they might simply change the way that LCP is calculated. However, my recommendation is to use this as a _last resort_ in the case that you've optimized everything and your site is _legitimately_ very fast and providing a good UX but this still occurs. Because really all Google is looking at is your *field data*, and what you have is lab data. How real users experience the page load is what _really_ matters.

Comment: @MikeCiffone Agree with your broader point, and this is off-topic, but do you have a source supporting your claim that Google no-longer penalise link schemes? They still [list](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175?hl=en#zippy=%2Cunnatural-links-from-your-site) it as a basis for a manual action penalty.

Comment: @GDVS https://youtu.be/0APf_IwEmZY?t=870 The manual action penalty does still exist, however, since "Penguin 4.0" back in 2016 the algorithm has been trying to ignore/devalue link spam in most cases. This is also why there's less of a need to use the disavow tool. Recall the [back and forth between Gary Illyes and Barry Schwartz](https://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2016/09/penguin-devalue-591x600.png). The exception (where you'd see that manual action) would be cases where theres a really strong pattern, then Penguin may penalize and distrust the site as a whole.

Comment: Though I ought to have said "link spam" or "buying links" rather than "link scheme". The former was my intention, the latter I'd associate with PLNs and other "schemes" where yeah...probably going to get hammered for those.