# Core Web Vitals - Field data difference Mobile vs Desktop

Tags: seo, html, javascript, css, core-web-vitals

I am observing a strange problem related to Core Web Vitals, I have same website for both mobile and desktop(same server/same page/same DOM size) but I when I look into search console I get different validated data. Almost all Mobile urls are passed but on the other hand almost all the urls on desktop are yellow what could be the reason for that?

Please refer to screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: This isn't necessarily strange. The two graphs show different experiences on different platforms, so won't agree with each other if you have platform-specific performance issues. I suggest going through the report and doing some digging — What is it failing on? What do the diagnostic tools show you? — and, if necessary, submit a more specific question.

Comment: I agree with @GDVS this is not that strange. You need to take the time to properly audit your performance. I offered this advice in my answer to [your question about LCP](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/138210/core-web-vitals-lcp-is-being-recounted-on-element-outside-viewport). Out of curiosity, what CMS does your site use? How is the site built (e.g. custom theme or framework/page builder)?

Comment: Also, can you run a web vitals test on [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/) and upload a screenshot of the waterfall?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues that could be affecting your desktop field data:

- Desktop users connection speed
- Desktop users geolocation
- Desktop ads banners
- JS/Images on the responsive website (maybe the responsive version for mobile removes certain heavy components and makes it really fast)
- ...

My first recommendation would be to analyze desktop and mobile versions using https://pagespeed.web.dev/ or https://gtmetrix.com/. That would give you more insights into speed problems in the desktop version.

After that, use the [CrUX dashboard](https://web.dev/chrome-ux-report-data-studio-dashboard/) to analyze the evolution of the different devices (tablet, phone, and desktop) in order to know if it's a recent problem that happened suddenly as GSC shows or if it has been changing over the time.

[image]